# in SwiftUI how do I determine view to show based on async call

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to control the flow of my app when it first appears based on an async call to see if the user is logged in or not.

If this call is synchronous I can do a simple switch or if else to determine the view to show.

But I don't know how to handle the flow based on an async request.  So far this is what I have done but changing the state var does not change the view which is displayed.  The following is in the app file @main function:

```
enum LoginStatus {
    case undetermined
    case signedIn
    case signedOut
}

@main
struct SignUpApp: App {
    
    @State var loginStatus: LoginStatus = .undetermined
    
    public init() {
        getLoginStatus()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch loginStatus {
            case .undetermined:
                Text("SigningIn")
            case .signedIn:
                EnterAppView()
            case .signedOut:
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getLoginStatus() {
        someAsyncFunctionToGetSignInStatus { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    self.loginStatus = .signedIn
                case .failure:
                    self.loginStatus = .signedOut
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I imagine this is a common task and wondering what the best way to handle it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but generally with async calls, you're probably going to want to move them into an ObservableObject rather than have them in your View code itself, since views are transient in SwiftUI (although the exception may be the top level `App` like you have).

```
class SignInManager : ObservableObject {
  @Published var loginStatus: LoginStatus = .undetermined
  
  public init() {
        getLoginStatus()
  }

  func getLoginStatus() {
        someAsyncFunctionToGetSignInStatus { result in
            //may need to use DispatchQueue.main.async {} to make sure you're on the main thread
            switch result {
            case .success:
                self.loginStatus = .signedIn
            case .failure:
                self.loginStatus = .signedOut
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@main
struct SignUpApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var signInManager = SignInManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch signInManager.loginStatus {
            case .undetermined:
                Text("SigningIn")
            case .signedIn:
                EnterAppView()
            case .signedOut:
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enum LoginStatus {
case undetermined
case signedIn
case signedOut
}

@main
struct SignUpApp: App {

```
@State var loginStatus: LoginStatus = .undetermined

public init() {
    getLoginStatus()
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        switch loginStatus {
        case .undetermined:
            Text("SigningIn")
        case .signedIn:
            EnterAppView()
        case .signedOut:
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}

func getLoginStatus() {
    someAsyncFunctionToGetSignInStatus { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success:
                self.loginStatus = .signedIn
            case .failure:
                self.loginStatus = .signedOut
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}